# Create a dataframe using list and dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
Device = [D1,D2]
out1=[42,145]
out2 = [0,1]
data = [{'A': '0.3%','B':'0.5%','C':'0.6%'},{'A': '1.3%','B':'2.5%','C':'0.6%'}]
```

I WANT THE OUTPUT LIKE:

```
Device   output     data
D1        42/0      0.3%/0.5%/0.6%
D2        145/1     1.3%/2.5%/0.6%
```

So, the output should be in the format out1[0]/out2[0]  and  out1[1]/out2[1]
and the data column should be in the format 
data[0]['A']/data[0]['B']/data[0]['C']

PLease help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
Device = ["D1","D2"]
out1=[42,145]
out2 = [0,1]
data = [{'A': '0.3%','B':'0.5%','C':'0.6%'},{'A': '1.3%','B':'2.5%','C':'0.6%'}]



df = pd.DataFrame({'Device': Device,
                   'output': ["{}/{}".format(*i) for i in zip(out1, out2)],
                   'data': ["/".join(i.values()) for i in data]})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Device output            data
0     D1   42/0  0.3%/0.5%/0.6%
1     D2  145/1  1.3%/2.5%/0.6%
```

Answer (score 0):

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J55UY.png)
[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw9Mc.png)

```
Device = ['D1','D2']
out1=[42,145]
out2 = [0,1]
data = [{'A': '0.3%','B':'0.5%','C':'0.6%'},{'A': 
         '1.3%','B':'2.5%','C':'0.6%'}]
list1=[];list2=[]
for i in range(len(out1)):list1.append(str(out1[i])+"/"+str(out2[i]))
for i in range(len(data)):                                 
    list2.append(data[i]['A']+'/'+data[i]['B']+'/'+data[i]['C'])
list3={Device[0]:list1,Device[1]:list2}
df=pd.DataFrame(list3,index=[Device[0],Device[1]])
df.rename(columns={Device[0]:'output',Device[1]:'data'},inplace=True);df.rename_axis(index='Device')
```